# How to stop execution of a running background thread from main thread on swift while using DispatchQueue

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

```
 DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
    //This will run on the background queue
    self.writeValue(tag: GlobalData.WRITE_DATA, data: getDataForWrite(1) )
    self.writeValue(tag: GlobalData.WRITE_DATA, data: getDataForWrite(2) )
    self.writeValue(tag: GlobalData.WRITE_DATA, data: getDataForWrite(3) )
    self.writeValue(tag: GlobalData.WRITE_DATA, data: getDataForWrite(4) )
    self.writeValue(tag: GlobalData.WRITE_DATA, data: getDataForWrite(5) )
    // .....
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        //This will run on the main queue, after the previous code in outer block
        print("done writing data")
    }
}
```

I need to stop executing this thread from the main thread. How is it possible

Comment: To me it's unclear what you want.

Comment: This code will run asynchronously until all the statements executed. But I need to stop the the thread in between if anything go wrong on my main thread. How can I terminate this thread in between using some command from main thread?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think the best solution is to execute `DispatchWorkItem` in `async`:

> DispatchWorkItem encapsulates work that can be performed. A work item can be dispatched onto a DispatchQueue and within a DispatchGroup

so at the end your code might be:

```
let workItem = DispatchWorkItem {
   //.... writing stuff in background ....

   DispatchQueue.main.async {
      //.... done writing stuff, updating ui ....
   }
}
DispatchQueue.global().async(execute: workItem)
```

when you need to stop the execution just call `.cancel()`:

```
//.... but, if stuff goes wrong ....
DispatchQueue.main.async {
   workItem.cancel()
}
```

Comment: Please bear in mind that cancelling a work item will not cancel one that is already executing - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchworkitem/1780910-cancel

Answer (score 1):

You can use a BlockOperation

```
let blockOperation = BlockOperation {
    self.writeValue(tag: GlobalData.WRITE_DATA, data: getDataForWrite(1) )
    self.writeValue(tag: GlobalData.WRITE_DATA, data: getDataForWrite(2) )
    self.writeValue(tag: GlobalData.WRITE_DATA, data: getDataForWrite(3) )
    self.writeValue(tag: GlobalData.WRITE_DATA, data: getDataForWrite(4) )
    self.writeValue(tag: GlobalData.WRITE_DATA, data: getDataForWrite(5) )
    //...
}

let queue = OperationQueue()
queue.addOperation(blockOperation)
```

And at some point in time from your main thread you can cancel the operation:

```
blockOperation.cancel()
```

More info on [BlockOperation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/blockoperation)

More info on [OperationQueue](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/operationqueue)

Comment: What if I want to run the above operation in background queue?