# How to run Timer in custom Thread with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading

I have to make a simple task - singleview app with two buttons and three treads -

1. Start Button :

1a) create a thread T1 - the GPS location of the device is collected repeatedly every 3.0
seconds, and the results (as a string) are handed over to T3.

1b) create w thread T2 - the percentage usage of the device's battery is collected
repeatedly every B seconds, and the results (as a string) are handed over to T3.

1c) In Thread T3 data from T1 and T2 should be stored in array and do sth when there is more then x data.

2. STOP button - just stop all three threads

I am a total noob in iOS threading.

1. What do you think, what should i use - DCG like here: [DCG embed in DispatchWorkItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48280851/how-to-stop-execution-of-a-running-background-thread-from-main-thread-on-swift-w)
2. Should i create a threads in ViewController? Or maybe i should build kind of a threading manager in  a model part ?
3. How to communicate between threads - should i create a kind of listener in T3?
4. By now i have sth like this, but it doesn't work.

   ```
    class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {  

    var threadLocalication: Thread?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.threadLocalication = Thread.init(target: self, selector: #selector(getLocalization), object: nil)

        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

    }

    @objc func getLocalization() {
        print("I am here")

        let timerLocalication = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 3.0, repeats: true) { timer in
            print("timer after 3 seconds")      //NOTHING IS PRINTED after thread starts
        }

    }

    @IBAction func startButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        threadLocalication?.start()
    }
    @IBAction func stopButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        threadLocalication?.cancel()
    }
   }
   ```

Why nothing is printed after thread start?

Please ask these 4 questions, and give me any advice (what is wrong) and more generally - How Should i do this?

Comment: Please ask _one_ question.

Comment: Great... It doesn't have a sense, to post 4 questions with the same description.... All of these questions are connected

Comment: What makes sense is to ask one question about the one thing you need in order to get started, rather than a very broad "Please write this entire branch of my app for me". It isn't even obvious that the question has anything to do with threading! That's just something you have _assumed_ (also known as an x-y question). You need to step back and ask about the single thing you _really_ want to do, e.g. how to get the location every three seconds, without assuming threads, work items, or anything else.

Comment: I received this task to make using threads, it is not my personal desicion. But i get a point - my task in not great.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer to your question is "don't use Thread this way." The (very slightly) longer answer is that Timers rely on RunLoops and you've created a Thread that has no RunLoop, and also you've destroyed your thread as soon as you created it. But you shouldn't use Thread this way anyway. In fact you should almost never use Thread in iOS development.

The problems you've described don't need anything like this. But if you find something where you think you really do need a Thread, first read Apple's [Migrating Away From Threads](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/ThreadMigration/ThreadMigration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH105-SW1).

If in the end you really did need a Thread, then you need to study the docs for [Thread](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/thread#). Almost every line of code here is incorrect, so rather than correct them all, start by reading the doc and then asking a new question. This isn't how you start a Thread, it isn't how you stop a Thread, and it isn't how Timers work. (The API is not obvious, so I understand why you wrote it this way. It's just not what you want at all.)

Updating location the way you've described should just be handled by responding to the delegate callbacks from the location manager. If you *really* needed check periodically, then you'd just use a standard Timer. There's no need for DispatchQueues, Threads, or anything else. Timer does all the work (it uses a RunLoop).

Similarly, battery monitoring should not be done with Timers. You want to turn on [`UIDevice.isBatteryMonitoringEnabled`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidevice/1620045-isbatterymonitoringenabled) and then listen for notifications. If you needed to poll, then again, a simple Timer is all you need.

Whenever possible, you want to let the system call you when things change. If you find yourself polling something, you're usually doing something wrong. But when you really do need to poll, Timer is the most common and simplest tool.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Generally it is my task to make, even if threads are useless and inappropriate here, i still have to make it with threads.

Comment: That's going to be a lot of very useless work (much more code and less efficient on device), but if "use a Thread" is somehow a requirement (well, then first, get another creator of requirements, because they don't know how Cocoa development works…) start by reading the Threading Programming Guide. It will explain most of it. It will seem very complicated for this simple thing because it's a horrible way to do it. https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/AboutThreads/AboutThreads.html

Comment: After reading the Guide, you will probably have more questions that will be fine to ask here. You'll need to preface every question with "I know that a thread is the worst way to do this, but humor me" because every experienced developer on Stack Overflow will try to correct this mistake. If "use a Thread and also a Timer" is the requirement (because you want to port this to OS X 10.5? hahaha), then make sure to study RunLoop, because Threads don't start their own RunLoop by default and so the Timers won't fire.