# multithread task, Threads in ViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading

I have to make a simple task - singleview app with two buttons and three treads -

Start Button :

1. create a thread T1 - the GPS location of the device is collected repeatedly every 3.0 seconds, and the results (as a string) are handed over to T3.
2. create w thread T2 - the percentage usage of the device's battery is collected repeatedly every B seconds, and the results (as a string) are handed over to T3.
3. In Thread T3 data from T1 and T2 should be stored in array and do sth when there is more then x data.

STOP button - just stop all three threads

I am a total noob in iOS threading. Unfortunately, App MUST use threads even if it is not necessary. Where should i create threads? Can i create them in ViewController class? Or maybe i should create a kind of singleton class to create and run threads (in a model part) ?

Comment: Why must the app use threads if not necessary? I'm assuming this is a programming assignment? Are they _really_ saying that you must “create” threads? Generally, nowadays, we never create our own threads, but rather use Grand Central Dispatch and use its “worker threads”. Or is your programming assignment really to not avail yourself of this contemporary GCD library for which we do practically all of our multithreaded programming and create your own `Thread` instances (which is practically an anachronism now)? I would suggest that you ask whether Grand Central Dispatch is permissible.

Comment: Yes, you should put this in a singleton model class. (It would probably be helpful to folks if you would explain why you have this requirement. I wouldn't even classify this requirement as "bad." It's silly, like someone is playing a cruel trick on you by assigning it.)  For others reading along, this is a continuation of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64666747/how-to-run-timer-in-custom-thread-with-swift

Comment: yes, it's programming assignment. I guess that i'm going to use GCD even if it's forbiddden :)

Comment: You don't even need (or want) GCD for this but, if anyone asks, "GCD manages threads for iOS" is a true statement. (It's misleading, but it's true.) So GCD would be the closest correct thing to what you've described. If you want to be clever, use DispatchSourceTimer (this is the GCD equivalent of "Timer"). If you want to be simple, use `DispatchQueue.asyncAfter` and just call it again after it completes. Best of luck.

Comment: Thank you vey much.I assume that i will be able to make T1 and T2 with DispatchSourceTimer, but still i dont know how to make T3. I wil try and eventually ask another question with my problems. :)

Comment: If sb is interested, this is continuation and my solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64681912/two-dispatchsourcetimers-sharing-one-resource-error-multithread-task