# two DispatchSourceTimers sharing one resource error, multithread task

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading

I have to make a simple task - singleview app with two buttons and three treads -

Start Button :

create a thread T1 - the GPS location of the device is collected repeatedly every 3.0 seconds, and the results (as a string) are handed over to T3.

create w thread T2 - the percentage usage of the device's battery is collected repeatedly every B seconds, and the results (as a string) are handed over to T3.

Data from T1 and T2 should be stored in array with limited positions (maxData).
In Thread T3, if array reaches maxData data should be send to the server (URL) via HTTP. Then clear array

STOP button - just stop all three threads

I am a total noob in iOS threading. Unfortunately, App MUST use threads even if it is not necessary. In my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64670183/multithread-task-threads-in-viewcontroller), [Rob Napier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/97337/rob-napier) suggested to use DispatchSourceTimers.

I'm close to find a proper solution, but sth is still wrong. When i clear array and post, single data from DispatchSourceTimer **is LOST**. I guess, that sth is wrong with **concurrentDataQueue.async(flags: .barrier)**, and i have to block reading of array somehow (?)

Class BackgroundThreadTimer is just wrapper for DispatchSourceTimers taken from
[medium article](https://medium.com/over-engineering/a-background-repeating-timer-in-swift-412cecfd2ef9)(RepeatingTimer)

```
//partly Pseudocode
var counter = 0
var data = [String]()
var maxData = 5
var counterInt = 0

var concurrentDataQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "dataCleanAndPostQueue", attributes: .concurrent)

var timerLocalization = BackgroundThreadTimer(timeInterval: 2)
timerLocalization.eventHandler = {
    //do sth and receive String x with actual localization
    //...
    concurrentDataQueue.async(flags: .barrier) {
        appendAndPost(phoneInfo: String(counterInt) + ": " + x)
        counterInt += 1
    }
    
}

var timerBattery = BackgroundThreadTimer(timeInterval: 3)
timerBattery.eventHandler = {
    //do sth and receive String x with actual battery level
    //...
    concurrentDataQueue.async(flags: .barrier) {
        appendAndPost(phoneInfo: String(counterInt) + ": " + x)
        counterInt += 1
    }
    
}

func appendAndPost(phoneInfo: String) {
    if data.count < maxData {
        data.append(phoneInfo)
    } else {
        let arrayString = data.joined(separator: "; ")
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            //post arrayString to http
            print(arrayString)
        }
        data = [String]()
    }
}

//when start pressed
timerLocalization.resume()
timerBattery.resume()

//when stop pressed
timerLocalization.suspend()
timerBattery.suspend()
```

Could sb help? Is my
diagnosis proper? And how to fix this.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is the data queue concurrent? If everything you’re going to dispatch is with barrier, then that’s a sign that you probably should just use a serial queue and then no barriers are needed.

Comment: Now i get it, unfotunately i copied it from singleton class, where strong references are kept. So my BackgroundThreadTimers works fine. And i understand why it should be a serial queue, i've already changed it, but still sth is wrong.

Comment: Some unrelated (and very minor) observations, if you don’t mind. I’d suggest eliminating `counter` and `counterInt` properties, as you’re not using them (and they’re unnecessary). I’d also pick a different name for the array of items because the name `data` would often only be used for a `Data` object. And, again, `concurrentDataQueue` should just be `dataQueue` and it should be a serial queue.

Comment: I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `appendAndPost`, you are appending result only if the count is less than `maxData`.

But let’s imagine that you called this where you already had five items in the array. In that scenario, you start the request, but you’re never doing anything with the supplied value.

I would advise appending the value regardless, and sending if the `count` hits the threshold:

```
func appendAndPost(phoneInfo: String) {
    data.append(phoneInfo)

    if data.count >= maxData {
        // create your request and send it

        ...

        // reset `data`

        data = []
    }
}
```

Comment: GREAT, thank you very much!! It was sa simple... i was looking for strange mistakes.